# Database using in other app?

Tags: android, eclipse

There are two app
1) database app
2) contact app
I want to use database of **database app** in contact app.how will it be done.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a content provider. Take a look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html